# how to add label inside expanded panel sapui5

Tags: javascript, dialog, panel, sapui5

Hi I have a dialog witch contains a panel that I should expand it and display a text / label or another controller with some text.
I managed to do the panel stuff but I don't know how to display the label inside the expanded panel.(I can't find any examples made in js without doing it in xml)

here is my code:

```
var panel = new sap.m.Panel("panel-1", {
            /*      justifyContent : sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.Center,*/
                    headerText:(oError.message),
                    width : '100%',
                    expandable: true
                });
var dialog = new Dialog({
                title: "There was an error while trying to resend the message",
                contentWidth: "500px",
                resizable: true,
                type: 'Message',
                state: 'Error',
                /*content: new sap.m.Label({
                    id : 'labeldialog',
                    justifyContent : sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.Center,
                    text: JSON.parse(oError.response.body).error.message.value,
                }),*/
                content: [panel],

            beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                text: 'Close',
                press: function () {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),

            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });

        dialog.open();
```

What should I use to achieve a control in such a way to put a string or a parameter in the collapsed part. thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
var panel = new sap.m.Panel("panel-1", {
                headerText:(oError.message),
                width : '100%',
                expandable: true,
                content: [ new sap.m.Text("someId", { "Your message here" })]
            });
```